# How to augment a list in python?

Tags: python, matlab

I have a simple for loop in matlab:

```
x = [];
for i = 1:n
   x = [x; myfun]
end
```

How can I do this in python?

Suppose I have a function called `myfun` which return some matrix `M` of size unknown.
I would like to have:

```
i = 1
x = M
i = 2
x = [M
     M]
i = 3 
x = [M 
     M 
     M]
```

N.B. I have to augment the size of `x` from `1` to `n` in the `for` loop and I don't know in advance what will be the size of `x`.

Comment: x.append()? x.extend()? Better read up.

Comment: Could you be more clearer in the question please .Anyway I think you linking to https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: How does `n` relate to `myfun`?

Comment: I think you want `for i in range(1, n+1): x.append(whatever)`

Comment: For MATLAB and Python, dynamic reassignment of an array or sequence is very slow and inefficient. Since you know you are going to call `myfun(a)` exactly `n` times, you can use [`arrayfun(func, A)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) in MATLAB and [`map(func, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to pass an iterable of args from `a1 ... a_n` to `myfun(a)` and get a sequence of outputs. Then you can append or concatenate this to the previous `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=[]
for i in xrange(n):
    x.append(i)
```

Output:
x=[0,1,2,...n-1]

Comment: You can also achieve the above using a list comprehension: `x = [i for i in xrange(n)]`.  Doesn't really help with the above answer, but it's probably more Pythonic.

Comment: Why even use a list comprehension? In Python 2, use `x = range(n)`, Python 3 `x = list(range(n))`.